# プログラムをコピペして実行してもエラーが出ます

Tags: google-colaboratory

以下の動画を参考にしているのですが、ここでつまずいてしまいます…どうすればいいでしょうか？

[コードはコピペで。無料のAIイラストstable diffusionをGoogle Colaboratoryを用いて使用する方法【ゆっくり解説】【VOICEROID解説】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyQfQYwvxlY)

実行したプログラム

```py
import torch 
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline 
# make sure you're logged in with `huggingface-cli login` 
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", revision="fp16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token=True)
```

実行結果

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a78234f208e2> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import torch
----> 2 from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
      3 # make sure you're logged in with `huggingface-cli login`
      4 pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", revision="fp16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token=True)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diffusers'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: 環境構築はどのようにされましたか？環境構築方法について記述されると回答者が回答しやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: 「この方の動画を参考にして」ではなく, どのような手順で操作を行ったか記すとよいでしょう (セルに入力した内容)。セルに入力した内容が質問通りなら, 確かに動かないはず。(動画に記されてる手順を踏んでいないので)

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyQfQYwvxlY&t=2s)の説明欄には下記記述がありましたが、こちらは読まれていますでしょうか？読まれていないのであればこちらを実行されると課題が解決するかもしれません。

```
2023年2月20日追記

■2022/12/18 追記（その３）で書いてあるプログラムですが、概要欄に記述してあるものが省略されて表示されてしまっています。
なので、プログラムをコピーしてエラーが出る方は、省略されている部分を書き直していただくか、以下のプログラムをご利用ください。

1.
# Google Driveをマウント
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd /content

# 必要ライブラリをインストール
! pip install diffusers==0.8.0 transformers scipy ftfy pytorch_lightning fire gradio
! git clone https://github.com/lisa-smallbird/Stable-Diffusers-Misc.git misc
! cp -prf misc/.* ./
from diffusion_client import DiffusionClient
dc = DiffusionClient()
```